# How to avoid duplicate entries of column in REALM database?

Tags: swift, realm

Can we avoid duplicate entries of the column in REALM database?
Eg. I have entries like 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 4 3 3 3 3 2 2 6 6 6

I want to show 2 3 4 5 6 only.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to filter the entries before adding them or adding a validation to prevent the realm to take duplicated entries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i prevent duplicates in RealmSwift List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513937/how-do-i-prevent-duplicates-in-realmswift-list)

Comment: I have duplicate entries in realm database, when I displaying that values to my collection view, I don't want duplicate value.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ahmad F said, specify if you want to do it after or before storing them.

In case you want to filter them AFTER storing you can go with something like this:

```
return realm.objects(YourObject.self).value(forKeyPath: "@distinctUnionOfObjects.entryKey")
```

Answer (score 0):

if using realm version 3.10  you can using

```
Results..distinct(by: )
```

if using Old version - before Realm 3.10 try this

```
func uniq<S : Sequence, T : Hashable>(source: S) -> [T] where S.Iterator.Element == T {
        var buffer = [T]()
        var added = Set<T>()
        for elem in source {
            if !added.contains(elem) {
                buffer.append(elem)
                added.insert(elem)
             }
        }
        return buffer
    }
```

using func

```
  uniq(source: realm.objects(Object.self))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think you should add the primary key in your class definition.
And it will help you to avoid duplicate items.